# What property is in jenkins' authorization matrix to not inherit global authorization in config.xml of a job?

Tags: xml, jenkins, config

```
<hudson.security.AuthorizationMatrixProperty>
  <GlobalInhertianceProperty>false</GlobalInheritanceProperty>
</hudson.security.AuthorizationMatrixProperty>
```

I assume it looks something like this, BUT I cannot find the value anywhere! Such a pain.

(the GlobalInhertianceProperty is not accurate, I am just giving an example of it)

P.S. I searched far and wide on the internet for a while and couldn't find this information, so any links to resources for other jenkins' issues would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

After hours of toil, I figured out that you can just set the inhertiance property in the GUI to true, then do a config call. It shows in that config.xml.

After that I used **Nokogiri** to parse the xml.

**THE BIGGEST TRICK!!!** You must place the tag before any other. The block is:

```
<blocksInheritance>true</blocksInheritance>
```

But it must go above the permission tags

e.g.

```
<hudson.security.AuthorizationMatrixProperty>
   <blocksInheritance>true</blocksInheritance>
   <permission>hudson.model.Item.Read:anonymous</permission>
   <permission>hudson.model.Item.Read:user</permission>
</hudson.security.AuthorizationMatrixProperty>
```

If it is below those it will not work because they programmed it poorly.